# awk shell variables not working

Tags: ksh

Hi I'm using GNU awk version 3.1.5 and I've specified 2 variables in a KSH script

```
PKNAME= ls -lt /var/db/pkg | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f9
PKDATE= ls -lt /var/db/pkg/$PKNAME/ | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f6-8
```

I'm trying to prove that I'm getting the correct output, by running a test using

```
echo bar    
awk -F, -v pkname="$PKNAME" -v pkdate="$PKDATE" 'BEGIN{print pkname, pkdate, "foo"; exit}'
echo baz
```

The output from this results in 2 blank spaces and foo, like so

```
bar
  foo
baz
```

I have tried, double quoting the variables, single quotes and back ticks. Also tried double quotes with back ticks.

Any ideas why the variables are not being executed? I'm fairly new to awk and appreciate any help! Thanks

I suppose it is possible that it is not possible to run a sub shell comand within an awk statement. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with awk. The problem is in the way you're assigning your variables. Your lines should be like this:

```
PKNAME=$(ls -lt /var/db/pkg | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f9)
```

There can be **no spaces** around either side of an assignment in the shell.

At the moment, you're running the command `ls -lt ...` with a variable `PKNAME` temporarily assigned to an empty string. In subsequent commands the variable remains unset.

Your awk command should remain unchanged, i.e. the shell variables should be passed like `-v pkname="$PKNAME"`. As an aside, it's generally considered bad practice to use uppercase variable names, as these should be reserved for internal use by the shell.

Comment: Awesome! This works, the example I was working from were strings and not commands which is why I was quoting.  Thanks alot!

Comment: I will change the variables to lowercase, I had attempted to export them as environment variables to use and never changed them back. I appreciate your assistance!